# How do I get Adobe Flash Player to open files on the net again?

Tags: firefox, flash-player

I have Windows XP Pro x64 and I use Firefox as my browser.

When I go to http://www.weather.com/weather, there are videos listed on the right hand side.  I used to be able to click on the video title and they would open.  I had a problem with my pc and had to do a system restore to after Adobe was installed but the files at this website stopped opening.  All I get is a black box.  I uninstalled Adobe and reinstalled these programs one at a time but the files still don't open:

- Adobe Flash Player 17_a
- Flash_player_ax Flash Player for Internet Exporer - ActiveX  (I occasionally use IE8)
- Adobe Flash Player - Active-x for Windows
- install_flash_player NPAPI for Firefox
- Adobe flashplayer17ax_a_install
- Adobe install_flashplayer17x32_aaa_aih
- Adobe Shockwave Installer Slim 12.1.4.155

They're the latest versions from the Adobe website.

In Add/Remove Programs, Adobe Flash Player 17 Active X and Adobe Flash Player 17 NPAPI are listed but there's no size to them, the "Size" field is blank.  The other Adobe programs that I installed aren't even listed there, and it's the the same with Revo Uninstaller.

I ran Avast, BitDefender, MBAM, Avira, SecurityCheck, and Spybot S&D and they showed only cookies so I don't think it's a malware problem.

Can anyone give me some help?

Comment: Your operating system isn't maintained since April 2014. You should consider upgrading to a modern version of Windows because Microsoft won't be releasing any security updates. Windows XP is not secure anymore even if you have antivirus program etc.

Comment: You didn't answer my question.  Why'd you bother?

Comment: He didn't leave it as an answer. Just a comment. A very valid one too

Comment: I'm not looking for comments, I'm looking for answers to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the Flash Plug-in is disabled. To enable it,

1. use the menu button to choose `Add-ons`
2. In the Add-ons Manager, select `Plug-ins` on the left
3. Find Flash in the list and choose `Always Active`

There is good troubleshooting information at Mozilla's site - [Flash Plugin - Keep it up to date and troubleshoot problems](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keep-flash-up-to-date-and-troubleshoot-problems)

Comment: I don't have a problem on IE8 x64 playing the videos on this page

Comment: That information is good to know, but this answer is for Firefox, as your question requested. Is the plug-in set to `always active` in Firefox?

Comment: Thanks for responding, Charlie.  I don't have a problem on IE8 x64, Firefox or Chromodo playing the videos on this page http://www.wfsb.com/global/category.asp?c=208507&autoStart=true&topVideoCatNo=default&clipId=9392382 but none of the browsers can open videos at http://www.weather.com/weather.  I don't know what the difference is between the sites tho.  In Firefox, I have all my add-ons enabled.

Comment: That is not what your question states. The way it is written, you lead us to believe there is a problem with the Flash plug-in. If you had told us that other sites play flash in all your browsers, I would have taken a different approach. Please edit the question to be accurate to the problem you are having, including all the details.

Comment: My initial question is correct.  There was a problem with my Flash Plug-In.  I think you misunderstood my last comment post.  I followed the link you gave me https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-extensions-themes-to-fix-problems and it led to "The Refresh Firefox feature."  It fixed the problem with Adobe Flash.  Videos now open at The Weather Channel on Firefox.  I didn't check IE8 or Chromodo because I use Firefox 99% of the time.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. Glad to hear you were able to resolve the issue. If this answer helped you do so, please select it as the accepted answer by clicking the check mark under the voting buttons to the left.